# In Laravel, Where I should fire events and emails in repo or in controller?

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern, laravel-mail, laravel-events, laravel-notification

I am using repository pattern in develop an application using laravel, my question is where I have to write code for fire events, send email or send an notification? and why?

Comment: There isn't any rule stating where events originate. It depends entirely on what you're doing and when you need it to be sent.

Comment: thank you for comment!

I am trying to find best practises for this question and how other developers thinking of it. so we can exchange our knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a broad question and many will come with their own opinions. In my opinion, form the context of `Laravel`, I would define types of my events depending on the operations.

So for example, as you mentioned email/notification events, I would like to think this way (This is a hypothetical example):

```
class UserController
{
    public function register(Request $request, UserRepository $user)
    {
        if ($user = $user->register($request->all())) {
            Email::send(...);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, an email should be sent to the user after the registration so I can use an event to do the same thing within the controller for example:

```
class UserController
{
    public function register(Request $request, UserRepository $user)
    {
        try {

            $user = $user->register($request->all());

            Event::fire('user_registered', $user);

        } catch(RegistrationException $e) {
            // Handle the exception
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I think, the event dispatching should be in the controller because it's the part of my application layer to control the application flow so, email sending event should be dispatched from controller. The `UserRepository` should not care about your application's flow, sending email to the user is not part of your `UserRepository`, so that's it.

Now, think about another hypothetical example, say you've a `delete` method in your `UserController` as given below:

```
class UserController
{
    public function delete(UserRepository $user, $id)
    {
        if($user->findOrFail($id)->delete()) {
            Post::where('user_id', $id)->delete();
        }

    }
}
```

Well, in this case, the deletion of the user involves some domain related operations so I would rewrite the method as given below:

```
public function delete(UserRepository $user, $id)
{
    try {

        $user->delete($id);

        return redirect('/users'); // show users index page

    } catch (InvalidOperationException $e) {
        // Handle the custom exception thrown from UserRepository
    }
}
```

Notice that, there is no related operations took place in the delete method because I would probably fire an event inside the `UserRepository` because this delete action involves some other domain/business related operation and application layer should not care about it (in this case) because the deleting an user effects some other domain objects so I'll handle that event this way.

Anyways, this is just my way of thinking and it's just an opinion. Maybe in a real world situation, I could come up with a different idea so it's up to you, depending on the context you should think about it and finally there's no recommended way in Laravel, you can even use `Models` to fire events, so just keep it simple, make the decision depending on your context that fits well.

Comment: Thank you! for full detailed answer. Almost I have same thinking but I am curious to see how developers thinking to find best practises lets see others what they have.

Anyway, I liked your answer.

Comment: This is a perfect answer, I noticed that you mentioned the application layer, are there other layers? where can I learn about these layers? this is the first time I read about that

Comment: @Ivandez, search about `MVC` design pattrern.